# How pack multiline key=value string to array of objects?

Tags: json, jq

I have multiline string like

```
a=aValue
b=bValue
c=cValue
a=dValue
b=eValue
c=fValue
```

How using jq get json like this?

```
[
  {"a": "aValue", "b": "bValue", "c": "cValue"},
  {"a": "dValue", "b": "eValue", "c": "fValue"}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have any problem with slurping the input, this should do the trick:

```sh
jq -R -s '[ split("\n") | map(split("=") | {(.[0]): .[1]}) | _nwise(3) | add ]' file
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Doj1wBdid8)</sup>

`_nwise(n)` is an undocumented internal function that given an array emits a stream of subarrays of length `n`. You can see how it's implemented [here](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/d18b2d078c2383d9472d0a0a226e07009025574f/src/builtin.jq#L84). For everything else, see the manual.

If values may contain equals signs, use `.[1:] | join("=")` instead of `.[1]`.

For a generally-applicable, memory-friendly approach, see [peak's answer](/a/67734535/10248678).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer that is not tied to the number of distinct keys, and avoids slurping the lines (i.e., has minimal memory requirements):

```
jq -Rn 'foreach (inputs, null) as $in ({};
    if $in == null then .emit = .object
    else ($in | capture("(?<key>[^=]*)=(?<value>.*)") // null) as $kv
    | if $kv == null 
      then .
      elif (.object | . and has($kv.key)) 
      then .emit = .object | .object  = ([$kv]|from_entries)
      else .emit = null    | .object += ([$kv]|from_entries)
      end
    end ;
    select(.emit).emit )'
```

The trick here is to use `inputs,null` so that the "end of file" condition is handled properly.

Note that the above produces a stream, so if you want all the objects in an array, simply enclose the entire jq program in square brackets:

```
jq -Rn '[ .... ]'
```